Ctrl+? engages the Zoom in Visual Studio
I've been working in Visual Studio for 3 months.  There are times when I press Ctrl+A and the Editor starts Zooming in usually a lot, over 200%.   It's difficult to reproduce. It never Zooms out only Zooms in.  I thought at first, perhaps I am moving my scroll wheel while the CTRL key is down but to get it to zoom over 200% takes many scrolls.  I have never experienced this behavior in any other program, just Visual Studio.
I am using VS 17.11.4.
Is this happening to anyone else?  I hope to record this behavior one day but it is difficult to reproduce.  It did happen again today.
Nov 3, 2024.
It just happened again.  It happened on CTRL+X (which I have mapped to my Logitech Mouse) this time.  Zoomed to 176% (See below screenshot).

Thank you

I did a quick test in VS17.11.4 but failed to reproduce this issue. For this issue , i would suggest the following to troubleshoot:

The default shortcut for zooming in and out is the following. Looks like your shortcut has been changed. Please navigate to the Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard and search for the commands View.ZoomIn and View.ZoomOutto check if you have customized the shortcut to CTRL+X/A.

Zoom in  Ctrl+Shift+.   
Zoom out    Ctrl+Shift+,


Run the following command to reset your settings.

devenv /ResetSettings



Please check if you have installed any third-party extensions. If so, disable them temporarily. Then press CTRL+X to verify it.

If the issue persists, please consider updating the VS to the latest version 17.11.5 or repairing your VS from VS Installer.


Docs Referred:
Keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio
/ResetSettings 

I removed the Keyboard Shortcut for Zoom In.  I never had one for Zoom Out.  Hopefully this resolved the issue.  I'll mark this as the answer.  Fingers crossed it never happens again.  Thanks Dou.

So far the Zoom has not re-occurred after I deleted the Shortcut Dou.  That may have been the issue.  Thank you.  I'll post here if it happens again.

Thanks again for the answer to this Dou.  This annoyance hasn't happened since I removed the Shortcut in VS.

Dou it started happening again today many times.  It's quite annoying.  It might be something with my logitech mouse.  That being said I don't understand why it would be happening.

It's constantly happening now.  I installed VS 17.12.0 yesterday.

I reported this Microsoft Dou.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/CTRLC-enganges-the-Zoom-in-Visual-Studi/10789123?ref=native&refTime=1731524283236&refUserId=4829de4a-2921-6fa5-99d7-4fa565473a1a
